# How to disable seekbar tracking beyound certain progress range

Tags: android, seekbar

I have SeekBar which tracks some downloading progress. Now I want to disable seek bar tracking when user taps the seekbar beyound the current progress.

That is if I've downloaded 50% of a file my seekbar is half-green, half-empty (second half is empty). I want to prevent user tapping anywhere in the 2nd half but allow tapping anywhere in the 1st half

Comment: One way can be that you can do it manually, in the listener, if it comes above current again reset to current.........

Comment: why are you using a seekbar and not a progress bar? I dont see the reason why you would want them to be able to use a slider on downloaded content unless you were streaming.

Comment: @viv I do reset but it jumps every time then

Comment: @ASceresini I do streaming yes

Comment: @Alex : it jumps? Not understood. By reset i mean when user changes it's position, if it's greater than current you set it to current...

Comment: @viv What I now have is: user touches seekbar in a position which I consider 'not yet available'. The seekbar jumps in there then gets reset by onStopTrackingTouch handler. To prevent the jump which handler should I use?